# jQuery Mobile stopholding event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to call an event when the user stops holding on a tabhold event.

Something that would work like this:

```
$(document).on('taphold', 'someElement', function()
{
    doSomething()
});
$(document).on('tapholdrelease', 'someElement', function()
{
   stopDoingSomething;
});
```

The reason I want to do this is I have an html canvas element that I need to animate when the user is touching a div and then stop the animation when they stop touching it.

Any Ideas? Would using .mousedown() and .mouseup() events work on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events

```
function startup() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchleave", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
  log("initialized.");
}
```

> When the user lifts a finger off the surface, a touchend event is
>   sent. Similarly, if the finger drifts out of our canvas, we get a
>   touchleave event...